# The operation is not valid for the state of the transaction. Something wrong with TransactionScope

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, transactionscope

I implemented Transaction Scope in my application.
But i receive following error
**The operation is not valid for the state of the transaction.**
Here is my code

```
 try{
      using (System.Transactions.TransactionScope scope = new System.Transactions.TransactionScope())
                {
                    UpdateDataBase1();
                    UpdateDataBase2(); // this line throws error.
                    scope.Complete();
                }
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
     throw ex;//Inner exception is null
  }
```

Both Databases are on same server(Server1)(MSDTC service is running).

My Application is on different server(server2).

I googled around and found two post with the same problem.

[StackoverflowPost1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193154/the-operation-is-not-valid-for-the-state-of-the-transaction-error-and-transact)

and

[StackoverflowPost2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20051527/the-operation-is-not-valid-for-the-state-of-the-transaction)

I found that there may be 2 main causes for my problem (1) MSDTC service and (2) Transacation Scope cannot handle to open connections.

But when i test the same scenario in local it works. The above 2 possible causes work very fine.I dont know what happens when i host them.

help me.

Comment: What is the state of the transaction? Did an exception occur somewhere else, and did this cause the transaction to abort?

Comment: Yes, an exception occurs. But the innerText of the exception is null. Yes that causes the transaction to abort

Comment: if an exception occurred in `UpdateDataBase1();` you won't be able to use the same transaction in `UpdateDataBase2();` you could check the state of the transaction before calling `UpdateDataBase2();`